# How to split string in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to split string using textchanged event. 
example i have 10000853,154SSDAAS but i just want to retrieve only 10000583.
I try to use split but it doesn't work. Can someone help me.
Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub AssetTxt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AssetTxt.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim split() As String = AssetTxt.Text.Split(",")
        If split.Count > 2 Then
            AssetTxt.Text = split(0)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not something I can help with

Comment: There is no "textchanged function".  `TextChanged` is an event.  Your handler for that event is a method.  What you want is to split a string in the `TextChanged` event handler of (presumably) a `TextBox`. That's all irrelevant to the splitting though, because splitting a `String` is the same no matter where you do it.  You need to debug your code and work out exactly where it doesn't do what you expect. For instance, what is in `split` when you get to that `If` statement? If it's what you expect then the splitting is working and your issue is unrelated to that.

Comment: When you split your example string "10000853,154SSDAAS" you'll get two parts, but in your code you only do something if you'd get more than two parts.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for, you've disabled the split for two items:

```
If split.Count > 1 Then
```

Your original code would work for values like 10000853,154SSDAAS,123456